# How to select a button using css select

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

need help with `css select` syntax to select the `button`.

Please see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. Please don't post HTML as images. There are lots of CSS selector references on the web. You should read some of them and attempt to find your own answer. This question has been asked many times. Once you give it a try, if you can't get it working then come back and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the cssSelector patterns is:

```
tagName[attribute='value']...[attribute='value']
```

To select it's immediate child,  you could use '>' symbol (You might know this).

So, for your case one of the possible selectors is:

```
button[class='md-primary md-button ng-scope md-ink-ripple'] > span
```

There are several possible ways you can do this. You may go through the page for more:

http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

Comment: You don't want to use `button[class='md-primary md-button ng-scope md-ink-ripple']` because that is an *exact* text match. You want to instead use `button.md-primary.md-button.ng-scope.md-ink-ripple > span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `cssSelector` to locate `Drug and Alcohol` button :-

```
md-grid-list[md-cols='2'] button.md-primary.md-button[ng-click*='openCategory']
```

But I don't think this `cssSelector` could be unique, you can locate this button using their `text` which could be unique using `xpath` as below :-

```
.//button[normalize-space(.) = 'Drug and Alcohol']
```

Or

```
.//button[. = 'Drug and Alcohol]
```

Or

```
.//button[span[text() = 'Drug and Alcohol']]
```